# about wiimote wrapper class

Tags: c#, .net

I'm interested in how this is working and looked at the code. The important part is the warp matrix construction done using the computeSquareToQuad and computeQuadToSquare functions, but I don't understand them. Can you do an explanation or give some references about that?

Answer (score 1):

These two methods are used for translating camera space coordination and display coordinates to each other (`computeSquareToQuad` for translating from camera coordinates to display and `computeQuadToSquare` for reverse of it),

When you look at the world through  a camera, the result is a flat image and everything is distorted according to  perspective rules. (for example squares transform into trapezoids). this distortion can be encapsulated by a warping matrix called a **planar homography**.

you essentially need a 3x3 matrix for calculation (note the normally 4x4 matrix is used because it can be easily integrated in 3D pipelines)

for more information have a look at

http://www.cs.utoronto.ca/~strider/vis-notes/tutHomography04.pdf

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fVJeJMWZcq8